# Can't get UIButton to call block of code in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, uibutton

I am trying to call a large block of code to run once a button (GoButton) is clicked, I have tried doing it this way but it just crashes, I also sometimes get the error that my button is equal to nil. any advice? All of the code below works just fine without the button being there, I want it to run once pressed. Also I'm new to swift programming so sorry if this is really easy. Thanks

Code Below:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func GoButton(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let APIUrl = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Crowland&appid=***APIKEY***&units=Metric") else { return }


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: APIUrl) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()


            do {
                let weatherData = try decoder.decode(MyWeather.self, from: data)

                if (self.MainLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let gmain = weatherData.weather?.description {
                        print(gmain)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.MainLabel.text! = "Current Weather in: " + String (gmain)
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (self.LocationLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let gmain = weatherData.name {
                        print(gmain)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.LocationLabel.text! = "Current Weather in: " + String (gmain)
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (self.HumidityLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let ghumidity = weatherData.main?.humidity
                    {
                        print(ghumidity, "THIS IS HUMIDITY")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.HumidityLabel.text! = String (ghumidity)
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (self.WindLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let gspeed = weatherData.wind?.speed {
                        print(gspeed, "THIS IS THE SPEED")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.WindLabel.text! = String(gspeed) + " mph"
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (self.TempLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let ggtemp = weatherData.main?.temp {
                        print(ggtemp, "THIS IS THE TEMP")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.TempLabel.text! = String (ggtemp) + " c"
                        }
                    }
                }


            } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            }.resume()
            }
        }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
```

Comment: How are you initializing your button?

Comment: on which line it got crash or please update your question with crash result

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `GoButton` function is somehow inside your `viewDidLoad` method? This should definitely not be the case as [nested functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_202) are hidden from the outside world by default.

If you are using storyboard, the correct way to link a button click to an action is to do it through the storyboard and IBActions. There are very many video/text tutorials showing you how to do so. Here is a video tutorial that I personally liked because of its clarity given that you are new to Swift - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Opz3juSW43Q. (I neither own nor have any affiliation with the video content in this link, I am merely linking it here as I think it might be helpful).